# Word for making my knowledge of a topic more general/wide/formal?

Tags: word-request

I already had a lot of knowledge of a certain topic or field, but I never had any formal education in it. I gained my knowledge and skills because I used it for my work for a long time. Of course I only learned about the specific things which I needed, so there was also a lot I didn't know yet. Then I took a course on the field, which gave me a more general overview of the whole field and reviewed all the most relevant topics.

I am looking for a word to fill in the blank:

```
To _____ my knowledge of this field, I recently took a course.
```

To "solidify" jumps in my mind, but I don't think that really means what I want to say. "Fill in the gaps in" seems a bit too weak, since that seems to imply only very little still needed to be learned (or am I wrong?). Is there any other word that might convey what I am trying to say?

Answer (score 1):

I think the word you are looking for is **expand**. This means that you filled in the gaps in your knowledge and improved what you already knew from practical experience by learning the theory or other techniques.

Comment: Hmm, perhaps. Although I feel like it does not convey so much the gaps filled ... Maybe that's just me.

Comment: Technically, you are correct; however, pragmatically this is the normal word and people would assume you are referring to the very things Peter Jennings listed in the answer.  If you really meant to express that you were increasing your knowledge from a solid foundation, you would use another word, like "increase."